# Python: String replacement with JSON dictionary

Tags: python, json

I need to create a script in Python, for replacement of strings in a json file, based on a json dictionary. The file has information about patents and it looks like this:

```
{
  "US-8163793-B2": {
    "publication_date": "20120424",
    "priority_date": "20090420",
    "family_id": "42261969",
    "country_code": "US",
    "ipc_code": "C07D417/14",
    "cpc_code": "C07D471/04",
    "assignee_name": "Hoffman-La Roche Inc.",
    "title": "Proline derivatives",
    "abstract": "The invention relates to a compound of formula (I) wherein A, R 1 -R 6  are as defined in the description and in the claims. The compound of formula (I) can be used as a medicament."
  }
}
```

Initially I used a software that identifies, based on entities (ex. COMPANY), all the words that are written differently, but are the same. For example, the company "BMW" can be called "BMW Ag" as well as "BMW Group". And this dictionary has a structure like this (is only partially represented, otherwise it would be very long):

```
{
  "RESP_META" : {
  ,"RESP_WARNINGS" : null
  ,"RESP_PAYLOAD": 
    {
      "BIOCHEM": [
        { 
          "hitID": "D011392",
          "name": "L-Proline",
          "frag_vector_array": [
            "16#{!Proline!} derivatives"
          ],
          ...,
          "sectionMeta": {
            "8": "$.US-8163793-B2.title|"
          }
        },
        { 
          (next hit...)
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
```

Taking into consideration that the `"sectionMeta"` key gives me the patent ID and, for ex., `abstract`, `title` or `assignee_name`, I would like to use this information to find out in which patent will the replacement take place, and then based on the `"frag_vector_array"` key, find the word to be replaced, which always is between `{!!}`, for example `{! Proline!}`, and that word should be replaced by `"name"`, for ex. `L-Proline`.

I've tried something to replace the companies name, but I think I'm going the wrong way. Here is the code I started:

```
import json

patents = json.load(open("testset_patents.json"))

companies = json.load(open("termite_output.json"))

print(companies)

companies = companies['RESP_PAYLOAD']

# loop through companies data
for company in companies.values():
    company_list = company["COMPANY"]

    for comp in company_list:
        comp_name = comp["name"]

        # update patents "name" in "assignee_name"
        for patent in patents.values():
            patent['assignee_name'] = comp_name

    print(patents)

    # save output in new file
    with open('company_replacement.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(patents, fp)
```

Well any and all help is welcome.

Comment: `"frag_vector_array": [
        "16#{!Proline!} derivatives"
      ], [...]
        "sectionMeta": {
        "8": "$.US-8163793-B2.title|"
      }` -- this is invalid json. What do you mean by `[...]`? Is `"sectionMeta"` a key of `"frag_vector_array"`? If so, your indentation is incorrect.

Comment: @FHTMitchell It would be very long, if I put the whole json, `[...]` means like, there's more information there, and no, `sectionMeta` is not a key of `frag_vector_array`. Json is okay, I checked.

Comment: OK I fixed your indentation and made things a bit clearer

Comment: @FHTMitchell thank you :)

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @Ajax1234 the output I want is that in the file where the patents are, that the names get to be normalized. For example, that all companies have the same name (`Hoffman-La Roche Inc.` or `Roche Diagnostics`, should all be `Roche`.) That all the same genes, which can be called differently, also have the same name (and so on). It is still confusing?